# Unable to connect EC2 instance to RDS in same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

- The EC2 instance is in the same VPC and has a public IP.
- The RDS instance has an inbound Security Group rule allowing traffic from the EC2 Security Group.
- All Subnets have access to the Internet Gateway, and all subnets use the default Route Table

If I add the public IP address of the EC2 instance to the RDS security group, the connection works, however; an inbound rule on the Security Group within the same VPC should be sufficient.

What am I missing?

Comment: How is the app on the EC2 instance referencing the RDS instance? Via DNS name or IP address? If via IP address, is it using the public or private IP address of the RDS instance?

Comment: DNS name.  I assumed that is correct since that is static and should not change.  

Edit:  Using the public IP also fails.

Comment: It sounds like, for some reason, your traffic is going via the EC2 instance's public IP address (since it works if that IP address is in the RDS security group). Can you hop onto the EC2 instance and resolve the RDS DNS name (eg ping it) to see whether it comes back as a public or private address? You want it to be private.

Comment: It did come back with the public IP, which I tired but did not work.  However; I don't believe using the Private IP is recommended as it can change without warning:

https://serverfault.com/questions/601548/cant-find-the-private-ip-address-for-my-amazon-rds-instance

Comment: Correct. You should always use the DNS name. However, it should resolve as a Private IP, which will then work with the security group. Once we figure out how to get that resolving correctly, everything will work as you originally expected. Has something impacted the way the instance resolves IP addresses (eg not using the default DNS server provided by DHCP)? Is your VPC configured for "DNS Resolution=Yes" in the VPC console?

Comment: Ahh, yeah I did add a new DHCP option besides the default.  The RDS instance is in the default, whereas the EC2 instance is not. DNS Resolution is set to Yes.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement, but basically you need to make sure the EC2 instance can resolve domain names using the DNS server within the VPC (which is the 2nd IP address in the subnet range). This will then resolve the RDS DNS name to the private IP address and the security group will permit traffic.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear.  We added the RDS instance, then added a new AD using Directory Services, so we do have multiple DHCP options sets.  I will look at what you have said and see what I can do.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't suppose you do know how to deal with multiple DCHP sets?  I can't get it to resolve to my private DNS, even after deleting the old DHCP options set.  I've tried rebooting the RDS as well, but it still uses public.  It's getting very frustrating.

Comment: I suggest you do some experimenting... Create a new VPC. Launch a cheap EC2 instance and a cheap RDS instance in the VPC. Login to the EC2 instance and resolve the DNS name of the RDS instance. Confirm that it goes to the private IP address. If so, start comparing it to what you've got in your current VPC and figure out what's different (presumably either the **DNS Resolution** or **DHCP Options Set** settings). Worst case, you can use AWS support (they are very worthwhile!).